# Openoffice version form commandline

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice

I am using Ubuntu server which have only CLI. I want to run UNO service/Open office document converter service in that server. When I checked , that server already has one version of OO installed. How can I find the installed version of that OOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was installed via repository:

```
dpkg -l openoffice.org-core
```